# How do you add an old repository (Jessie) to the list of repositories apt-get can download from?

Tags: debian, apt

I'm currently working on Debian.

I've recently found a package I want to use apt-get to install onto my computer, but the only distribution of it is for the oldstable (jessie) repository. I'm currently using the stable (stretch) repository, and apt-get doesn't have the oldstable repository in 'sources.list.d'. How do I add the oldstable repository to that list?

Comment: I don't think apt-get can install it. But you can download it somewhere else and use deb to install it.

Comment: I've tried using a direct website download, but during the 'make' command it runs into an error of a directory missing, even though I can see the directory in the right spot. That itself is another question, and I don't want to run though the trouble of working that out.

Comment: After further research, I've decided to change the question to a more specific statement

Comment: Why would you have to use `make`? Do you really know the difference between "build a package" "download a package" "install a package"?

Comment: No... Sorry, I should look more into what I was saying and what I wanted.

Comment: I see the package under the oldstable repository, and I want to access it that way instead of working with tar balls and configuration. I've tried by downloading a tar ball and running through the configuration and make settings, and that isn't working. So I hope to just work it out this way instead.

Comment: Why do you want to add a repo for Jessie packages into your Stretch system? You are better off building it from source as installing it from a Jessie repo may not even be possible because it might try to pull other dependencies that are outdated.

Comment: Could you specify what exactly do you want? Build a software into a deb package and install it? Get an old official package and install it without regarding to all its old dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the repository the "usual way". Create a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` say `jessie` with the line:

```
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
```

You *may* then be able to install the package with `apt` after an `apt update`. However, there may be dependency issues and clashes etc.